# error: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly

Tags: git, github, curl

I am trying to push 2 folders into my github repo, was able to push other folder no issue. I got
this error msg:

- *Enumerating objects: 150, done.
  Counting objects: 100% (150/150), done.
  Delta compression using up to 8 threads
  Compressing objects: 100% (143/143), done.
  error: unable to rewind rpc post data - try increasing http.postBuffer
  error: RPC failed; curl 56 ioctl callback returned error 2
  send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
  Writing objects: 100% (149/149), 4.06 GiB | 64.68 MiB/s, done.
  Total 149 (delta 19), reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
  fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
  Everything up-to-date*

tried these from similar questions and no luck yet:

- git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1 **then** git push
- this error msg:
  *Enumerating objects: 150, done.
  Counting objects: 100% (150/150), done.
  Delta compression using up to 8 threads
  Compressing objects: 100% (143/143), done.
  error: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500
  send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
  Writing objects: 100% (149/149), 4.06 GiB | 52.00 MiB/s, done.
  Total 149 (delta 17), reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
  fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly*
  Everything up-to-date
- git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400 **then** git push
- this error msg: *Enumerating objects: 150, done.
  Counting objects: 100% (150/150), done.
  Delta compression using up to 8 threads
  Compressing objects: 100% (143/143), done.
  error: unable to rewind rpc post data - try increasing http.postBuffer
  error: RPC failed; curl 65 ioctl callback returned error 2
  send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
  Writing objects: 100% (149/149), 4.06 GiB | 48.70 MiB/s, done.
  Total 149 (delta 17), reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
  fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
  Everything up-to-date*

can someone please help me? I just want to upload the files so I can run my web app but need it to be on github for the way I need to run it, would greatly appreciate any help!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

GitHub has a hard limit on pack size which is 2 GiB.  If you attempt to push a pack larger than that, it will always fail.

If this data is all in one commit, then you'll have to fix that commit so it doesn't contain so much data.  You'd do that (only on a completely clean working tree) with `git reset --soft OBJECT-ID`, where `OBJECT-ID` is the commit before the one you added all the data.  You can then commit that data in several commits and push incrementally, as outlined below.

If this data is simply a large history with many commits, then you can do something like this:

```
$ git rev-list --reverse HEAD | perl -ne 'print unless $i++ % 5;' | \
    xargs -I{} git push origin +{}:main
```

That will push the repository five commits at a time.  If you just have a very large history, you could try 50000 instead, which might work.  If you have a large amount of data in subsequent commits (as in the case above), you may need to use 1 instead of 5.

Note that despite the message, you don't want to increase `http.postBuffer` here and [the Git FAQ explains why it shouldn't be necessary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-postbuffer).  GitHub is certainly not broken in the way required for that option to be effective (although in some cases people have broken proxies that they may use with GitHub), and so generally it just serves to waste lots of memory.