# Migration from Bitbucket to GitHub: HTTP 500 Error and Unexpected Disconnect

Tags: git, github, github-actions, bitbucket

I'm in the process of migrating a Git repository from Bitbucket to GitHub, and I've encountered some issues that I'm struggling to resolve. Here's the problem I'm facing:

During the migration process, when I push my repository to GitHub using the following command:

```
 git push --mirror github
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Enumerating objects: 310337, done.
Writing objects: 100% (310337/310337), 2.38 GiB | 226.92 MiB/s, done.
Total 310337 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 310337
error: RPC failed; HTTP 500
curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I've tried researching this issue and have checked GitHub LFS (Large File System), even increasing post buffer to 4000000000  `git config --global http.postBuffer 4000000000`
and GitHub credentials, but I'm still stuck. Can anyone provide insights or suggestions on how to resolve this HTTP 500 error and unexpected disconnect during the migration process?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75817473/error-rpc-failed-http-500-curl-92-http-2-stream-0-was-not-closed-cleanly/75817884#75817884) answer your question?